Bash builtin 'command' ignoring option '-p'
I am trying to add this to my ~/.bashrc and test for some commands, that already have aliases.
command -pv <command>

but it seems like the -p option that is supposed to force a path search is getting ignored.
Not sure if it's a bug to report so I decided to inquire in case i'm missing anything.
Tests
Bash Version: 5.2
Patch Level: 37
Release Status: release

I make sure its the shell builtin
$ type command
command is a shell builtin

$ command --help
command: command [-pVv] command [arg ...]
    Execute a simple command or display information about commands.

    Runs COMMAND with ARGS suppressing  shell function lookup, or display
    information about the specified COMMANDs.  Can be used to invoke commands
    on disk when a function with the same name exists.

    Options:
      -p    use a default value for PATH that is guaranteed to find all of
            the standard utilities
      -v    print a description of COMMAND similar to the `type' builtin
      -V    print a more verbose description of each COMMAND

    Exit Status:
    Returns exit status of COMMAND, or failure if COMMAND is not found.

Works on aliases
$ command -v pacman
alias pacman='pacman --color auto'

$ command -v grep
alias grep='grep --color=auto'

But completely ignores '-p' however specified.
$ command -pv grep
alias grep='grep --color=auto'

$ command -p -v grep
alias grep='grep --color=auto'

Here, I tried to sneak in an unknown option to make sure it detects '-p' but simply
ignores it.
$ command -p -v -x grep
bash: command: -x: invalid option
command: usage: command [-pVv] command [arg ...]

Extra notes
In the zsh shell, everything seems to work fine, the -p option is treated as it should (I am not including zsh tests because this is about bash).

I believe it works as specified: the alias shown by -v is the same with or without -p, but what changes is the context : the env var PATH should be different with -p than without. try : create a script.sh that just does a sleep 300, and execute: command script.sh, and do in another window a ps auxewww | tr ' ' '\n' | grep [P]ATH=,  and try the same while a command -p script.sh is running, and compare both PATH (You may have to define a specific PATH="${PATH}:/bin:/var" first to ensure that it differs from the "standard" one set by -p)


... it it seems like the -p option that is supposed to force a path search ...

A literal reading of help text quoted in the question doesn't imply anything like that. All -p does according to that text is make command use a default value for PATH, but it doesn't say that command will then skip alias, built-in, etc. lookups (nor does POSIX require this). With bash, I'd say you're looking for type -P:
type: type [-afptP] name [name ...]
    Display information about command type.

    For each NAME, indicate how it would be interpreted if used as a
    command name.

    Options:
[...]
      -P        force a PATH search for each NAME, even if it is an alias,
                builtin, or function, and returns the name of the disk file
                that would be executed

$ command -pv ping
alias ping='ping -c5'
$ type -P ping
/sbin/ping


This I have done, but the problem is, i have a ~/.shrc file that is sourced automatically by my bash and zsh, that works fine in bash,but not in zsh, i was leaning towards a way to work for all...

wait...did i mention that i also tried which...which works fine in zsh and bash...except on the third minimal system for temporary commands....(doesnt have which installed)...and the shrc file contains every alias and general initializations

I can find a way to use which, but its not gonna be fun, so any suggestions are still welcome

@Jore Don't try to write polyglot shell startup scripts, that will not work. Use separate setup scripts for bash, zsh and whatever other shell you may be using.

As Kusalananda says. But ff you must use a single file, test for variables like BASH_VERSION or similar and run different commands accordingly @Jore. (And don't use which in bash, if you can help it)

Or just use type -P for both zsh and bash @Jore. That's the command you really want anyway (see how even the help message of command explains that its -v is trying to be like type), so forget command and use type -P instead.

@terdon I hope you are aware that type -P only works for bash...zsh uses -p...

never mind anyways....i can hardcode the paths for now!...but it was worth mentioning

although...what everybody failed to explain is why zsh treats this as i think it should be treated...when i use -p...zsh ignores the aliases and uses path...also point out the difference of using the option in bash..cant seem to get it??

@Jore asking "why X doesn't do Y" is often pointless, as the answer is usually just: "because no one spent the time to implement that behaviour". As I said in the answer, there is no justification for your expectation in the bash docs or in the POSIX standard. You're welcome to raise a feature request with the bash developers to get bash to behave like zsh - maybe even create a patch to do so - but it will likely be rejected because it's not required by POSIX, and what you need can be obtained by type -P

@muru okay thanks for the help...but would you care to elaborate the difference of using the option?....doesnt seem to be well documented...that is if you know

@Jore I don't understand what you're asking. I've quoted the help text for type's -P above and it seems pretty clear to me.
